# bootstrap 4 row height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I try to have something like this with bootstrap 4[image]

with equal size in the height of green rows and red row

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6 B"><div class="card card-inverse" style="background-color: #333; border-color: #333;">
    <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/800/500/4" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    
    </div></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 G">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 B"><div class="card card-inverse" style="background-color: #333; border-color: #333;">
    <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/800/500/4" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    
    </div></div>
       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 B"><div class="card card-inverse" style="background-color: #333; border-color: #333;">
    <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/800/500/4" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    
    </div></div>
       <div class="col-md-12"><div class="card card-inverse" style="background-color: #333; border-color: #333;">
    <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/800/500/3" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    
    </div></div>
       </div>
    </div>   
       
        </div>
    </div>
```

All images have the same size and are responsive
but the problem is I can't get equal size in the height of green rows and red row

Comment: The images do not exist anymore... Please upload the images to stackoverflow next time and link them

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use the sizing utility classes...

- `h-50` = height 50%
- `h-100` = height 100%

---

http://www.codeply.com/go/Y3nG0io2uE

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6 B">
                <div class="card card-inverse card-primary">
                    <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/800/500/4" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 G">
                <div class="row h-100">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 B h-50 pb-3">
                        <div class="card card-inverse card-success h-100">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 B h-50 pb-3">
                        <div class="card card-inverse bg-success h-100">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 h-50">
                        <div class="card card-inverse bg-danger h-100">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

***Or***, for an *unknown* number of child columns, use **flexbox** and the cols will fill height. See the `d-flex flex-column` on the `row`, and `h-100` on the child cols.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6 B">
            <div class="card card-inverse card-primary">
                <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/800/500/4" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 G ">
            <div class="row d-flex flex-column h-100">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 B h-100">
                    <div class="card bg-success h-100">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 B h-100">
                    <div class="card bg-success h-100">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 h-100">
                    <div class="card bg-danger h-100">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/tgzFAH8vaW

Comment: Yes, it works but the original placeholder images no longer worked.

Comment: your second example looks different from the first.