# Equal height of columns in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a little non-conventional DIV in this design as shown below. I could use a height and do it but I want it to change dynamically:
[image]
For instance, if the DIV has more content and the height changes in one of the block on the right, the left DIV auto adjust it's height as well. I wonder if flex could help. Here's how it should change to:
[image]

I have this HTML so far:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-eq-height">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-8">
        <div class="black">
          <p>Bar Graph or Line Graph</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-4">
        <div class="red">
          <p>numbers</p>
        </div>
        <div class="purple">
          <p>numbers</p>
        </div>
        <div class="green">
          <p>numbers</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blue">
          <p>numbers</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
p { color: #fff; }
.black { background-color: black; }
.green { background-color: green; }
.red { background-color: red; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }
.purple { background-color: purple; }
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ar0m0p3a/)**

Comment: [Equal height columns with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33813871/3597276) |  [revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ar0m0p3a/2/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for this.

## Update

And another way:

https://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/ar0m0p3a/5/

```
.row-eq-height > [class^=col] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row-eq-height > [class^=col]:last-of-type div {
  margin: 10px;
}

.row-eq-height > [class^=col]:last-of-type div:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.row-eq-height > [class^=col]:last-of-type div:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.row-eq-height > [class^=col]:first-of-type .black {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

## Update

A better way with more specific classes:

https://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/ar0m0p3a/3/

```
.row-eq-height > [class^=col]:first-of-type {
  display: flex;
}

.row-eq-height > [class^=col]:first-of-type .black {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.blue p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Original way:

https://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/ar0m0p3a/1/

```
[class^=col] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

[class^=col] div {
  flex-grow: 1
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Could we use a specific class name instead of `col` or `div`? since I have other col and div in the page, it might create an issue

Comment: @ElaineByene Absolutely. Use a selector that makes sense for you.  I would first recommend learning about flexbox since it's a little tricky in the beginning.  Feel free to ask flexbox specific questions if you get stuck.  Happy to help.

Comment: @ElaineByene, I've updated with another implementation using more specific / semantic selectors.

Comment: Perfect! The original code was having issues with the other DIVs. Thank You so much :)

Comment: @ElaineByene, I've added a third way as well since the second way only ensuring that the left column (`.black`) was matching the height of the first column containing the four colors.  The third way makes sure the row is truly equal height.

Answer (score 19):

You're using Bootstrap 4, right? Bootstrap 4 implements flexbox by default and you can solve this very easy while using purely classes Bootstrap 4 provides:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-8 black">
          <p>Bar Graph or Line Graph</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-4 d-flex align-content-around flex-wrap">
        <div class="red">
          <p>numbers and more and so on and on and on</p>
        </div>
        <div class="purple">
          <p>numbers</p>
        </div>
        <div class="green">
          <p>numbers</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blue">
          <p class="mb-0">numbers</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ydjds2ko/

Details:

- You don't need the class `row-eq-height` (it's not in Bootstrap4
  anyway) because equal height is default.
- The first div with the class `col-sm-8` has the right height, it's just not visible with the black background, because the inner div has it's own height. I just removed the inner div and added the class `black` to the col. If you need inner div, give it the (Bootstrap4) class `h-100` which adjusts the height to the parent element.
- the div with the class col-sm-4 get's a the classes d-flex align-content-around flex-wrap. They're aligning the content divs. Bootstrap doku: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#align-content

  - Set the width of the divs inside this container at the widht of the parent with w-100
- Because the `<p>` adds a margin at the bottom, your blue div at the
  ends doesn't close flush with the black div. I added the class
  "mb-0", which sets the margin bottom to "0" so you can see it works.

That should work wether the right or left div is the one with the bigger height property.

Edit: added classes for content alignment.

Comment: That's so simple!! However, it doesn't work in this case: https://jsfiddle.net/huoaynb0/1/

Comment: You're right! The div items in the right col doesn't align themselves correctly on their own. Bootstrap covers this case too, fortunately.

You can make it work like that: https://jsfiddle.net/ydjds2ko/

Answer (score 6):

Here's a very simple **Bootstrap only** approach for this. You don't need any additional CSS.

https://www.codeply.com/go/J3BHCFT7lF

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8">
        <div class="black h-100">
          <p>Bar Graph or Line Graph</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="red mb-2">
          <p>numbers</p>
        </div>
        <div class="purple mb-2">
          <p>numbers with more lines of content that wrap to the next line</p>
        </div>
        <div class="green mb-2">
          <p>numbers</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blue">
          <p>numbers</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This uses the [Bootstrap 4 utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) to make the right column fill height.

---

Related:
[bootstrap 4 row height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375329/bootstrap-4-row-height)