# Does making a Bootstrap row d-flex make its columns equal heights?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Does making a Bootstrap 4 row d-flex make its columns equal heights?

Example,

```
<div class="row d-flex">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
       22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
       33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333</p> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>1</p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

`

Comment: It makes equal heights for the **col-md-6** div tags

Comment: Possible [DUPLICATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611092/equal-height-of-columns-in-bootstrap-4).

If you do paste your question in [Google Search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=making+a+Bootstrap+4+row+d-flex+make+its+columns+equal+heights&oq=making+a+Bootstrap+4+row+d-flex+make+its+columns+equal+heights&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2.722j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) you will find the solution:

Answer (score 0):

What are the proprieties for the "d-flex" class:

```
.d-flex {
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    display: -webkit-flex !important;
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
}
```

If you don't add extra CSS properties, you will have equal columns (equal height is default).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `d-flex` class to `align-items-stretch` should do it.

The Bootstrap 4 grid is flex by default.

Check the docs [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#align-items).